# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. it does not allow html inside node_modules

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, pouchdb, babel-loader

i am using simple vue project and i added a aditional package called  `vue add electron-builder`, my goal is  to trigger server.js file whenever i open my electron app. i am having pouchdb express inside server.js file.i called server.js inside backround.js.i know i am facing error due to babel  but i dont't know how to configure in my project.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      builderOptions: {
        win: {
          icon: './public/icon.ico'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 sourceType: 'unambiguous',
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ],
  ignore: [
    'src/entities/*'
]
}
```

i am facing error

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                       7:50:46 PM

```
 error  in **./node_modules/pouchdb-fauxton/www/index.html**<---this file is not allowing
```

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
**You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type**, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
> <!doctype html>
| <html lang="en">
| <head>

 @ ./node_modules/express-pouchdb/lib/routes/fauxton.js 7:32-66
 @ ./node_modules/express-pouchdb/lib sync ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./node_modules/express-pouchdb/lib/index.js
 @ ./backend_db/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--18-0!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty self explanatory: you need to add the webpack loader for html files.

```
npm install --save-dev html-loader
```

Then in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
          .rule('html')
          .test(/\.html$/)
          .use('html-loader')
          .loader('html-loader')
      }
}
```